# Centering Bootstrap Popover beneath button when main column is floated next to sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using a [Bootstrap Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and would like the popover to be horizontally centered with the bottom of my button. The button is up against the right column of the main content DIV, so it's pushing it over to the left instead of putting it on top of the main column and sidebar.

How can this be fixed?

[My JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/k0b4anLe/4/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger bs-docs-popover" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.bs-docs-popover').popover();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it solution good for you? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0b4anLe/5/)

I've add css class like this

```
.popover.fade {
    width: 100%;
}
```